# What are the alternatives to html5 session storage?(not local storage)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, session-storage

I want 2 javascript methods to access certain data without passing this data to any of the methods as arguments. Basically I want one method to set the data and other to consume that data using the objects already available in the browser and I want the solution to work with Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE8+ also iOS and android browsers. I believe session storage does not work on iOS. Is it correct? What are the drawbacks of session storage. I tried to append the data to the event object but it does not work in firefox and IE.

Comment: you can use webSQL same like SQL

Comment: OK, thank you, don't know much about it. I need to see how it works. Also does this work with all the browsers I mentioned?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage see this link and let me know then i will give you code for that

Comment: for phongap i think you have to use sharedpreferences  using javascript it is simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for data attributes instead of above mentioned approaches and they are working fine for me. IE9 and IE8 are presenting some issues which I need to tackle. In IE9 & IE8 the data attributes work sometimes and sometimes not. After I use the console to query data-attributes of the element, they start working.

Answer (score 2):

Although `sessionStorage` is available for iOS, you can do following for legacy support. You can use `window.name`. It lives through the session (i.e. until the browser tab gets closed):

```
var myData = {
  'foo': 'bar',
  'foz': 'baz'
};

window.name = JSON.stringify(myData);
```

And you can read it back:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(window.name);
```

This of course requires JSON support from the browser, which leaves very old browsers out of the scope.

Comment: Are there any other window object members which I can use that will work in the browsers I have mentioned? I believe you have more or less answered my original question.

Comment: No. `window.name` is the only property that will last through the session.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "global variable" (I put that in quotes because I'm not sure what it's actually called in Javascript). But basically you could just make an object in one of your javascript files and write to/read from it.

Something like

```
var data = { first: "first", second: "second" }
```

and just make as many variables in that object as you need. And a function would access it like

```
function(param) {
    var firstData = data.first;
}
```

Or I guess using cookies is closer to what you described as your own solution, but that seems like overkill if you just need to pass data between Javascript methods.

Comment: thank you, but this is not an option in my case because I don't want to introduce any additional object. I am looking for such "global variable" already available with all the browsers. I tried using event.target because that is what my lead suggested, but it is not working on firefox and ie.

Comment: Can you set a cookie then? All browsers support cookies. Something like document.cookie="data"

Comment: Yeah using cookie seems as a last resort but as you said, it would be an overkill.